# Nservicebus possible to publish an event when a message gets moved to error queue?

Tags: nservicebus

I have a saga that does a bulk import by creating a bunch of commands (It keeps track of the # of commands sent) then listens to an event indicating the task succeeded.  I would also like to be notified when the command fails (moves into error queue).

I want to take advantage of nservicebus's retry functionality so I don't want to simply wrap it in a try catch, I really only want to publish this event when it is moving to the error queue.

Is it possible to create another end point that handles the generated commands but listens to the error queue?  Or is there another better way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could count the number of retries in a saga property and publish a specific message if retries exceeded and the message would move to error queue.

Comment: btw. here is a complete and correct implemented solution: http://andreasohlund.net/2012/05/23/introducing-the-nservicebus-second-level-retries/

Answer (score 2):

You can take control over how the exceptions are handled using a [custom fault handler](http://adamfyles.blogspot.com/2013/02/nsb-custom-fault-handling-in-15-minutes.html)